# Hide the iframe in case of internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

So I'm making a widget that extracts some text from client's side, send it back to server for processing and embeds an iframe into client side. However, in case of any error, my client wants me to hide/remove the iframe altogether rather than generating a custom error page. I'm wondering what will be the best way to achieve this. Here's the script that I'm giving to the clients:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

if($(".single-post").length===1)
{ 
heading =$('.post h2').text();
heading =heading.trim();

link = $('.post h2 a').attr('href');

date = $('.post .meta .timr').text()

if($('div .entry p').text()!="")
para_full = $('div .entry p').text()
total_length = para_full.length;
if (total_length<3000)
{
text_send = para_full;
}
else{

tsstart = (total_length/2) - 250;
tsend = (total_length/2) + 250;
text_send = para_full.substring(tsstart,tsend );
}

if($('div .entry img')[0].src !=""  && $('div .entry img')[0].src != "undefined")
image_url = $('div .entry img')[0].src

if($('h3#comments').text()!="" && $('h3#comments').text()!="undefined")
{ 
no_of_comments = $('h3#comments').text()
l = no_of_comments.indexOf('Responses');
no_of_comments = no_of_comments.substring(0,l-1)

}
else
{
  no_of_comments=0;
}


$(".client_site_iframe").attr("src","http://mydomain.com/query?"+"&searchtext="+text_send+"&link="+link+"&imagelink="+image_url+"&heading="+heading+"&date="+date+"&full_text="+para_full);

}

})

</script>


<div class="client_site_container">
<iframe class="client_site_iframe" id="mysite_iframe" width="650px" height="205px" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>


</div>
```

One of the solution that I tried was to write a error handler function

```
myHandler = function(error) {
  document.getElementById('client_site_iframe').style.display = 'none';
}
```

which will be triggered for the following condition

```
<script>
if ($("#client_site_iframe html body").text().length === '')
{myHandler();}

</script>
```

but this didn't work due to same origin policy.In fact, I'm not able to access any HTML elements generated inside iframe using jQuery on client side. I'm wondering if there is any better way to achieve this, I'm very new to client side scripting so I'm not sure if this problem can be solved at all or someone recommended using AJAX request but I'm not sure how that will help me workaround cross origin policy.

Comment: tl;dr - When it's possible, it's better to use ajax instead of iframe, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. *EDIT: not possible in your case as it would trigger a cross origin exception*

Comment: the content of iframe is from another domain? shed some light on it.

Comment: Right... roger that. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the contents of the iframe, you could:

1. Hide the iframe by default
2. On successful load of the iframe content, use `parent.document.getElementById('client_site_iframe').style.display = 'block';` within the iframe source to show the iframe.

Comment: This will only work if iFrame source and parent source are on same origin, right ??

Comment: This would still trigger the Same-origin policy exception, as this is a cross origin request. (from the iframe to its parent)

Comment: Protocols, domains, and ports must match when trying to access an iframe's parent. As long as these are the same, this should be fine.